# Lua GameDev iOS - Code on win and mac

Tags: ios, lua

I am searching for a simple framework like http://getmoai.com where you can simply code a game in lua for iOS. I want to build it along with a friend. I am using a Mac, he prefers windows so the fw needs to be used in Windows 7. Preferably something like LOVE2D but then offcourse also for iOS!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with Moai?

Comment: You pay for more traffic isn't it? (not even sure what traffic is in their eyes.) If the app becomes popular it won't run because of the payment rescrictions isn't it?

Comment: searched a bit furture, I mean the Moai Cloud thing. Can't you build an app without that cloud.

Comment: Why do I even need that cloud? I don't need to get the cloudthings, just want to make a simple offline game. (maybe highscores but that's it)

Comment: You would need to distribute the game somehow.

Comment: Just upload to the AppStore, right? Can't I do that myself? Also, can you even code and test on windows? Can't find tutorials. Just saw it on a review somewhere.

Comment: Says it works with Chrome, and C++/Lua both run on Windows. I'm betting documentation comes with it. Maybe you should do a bit more research, then ask your question again when you know more about your options and what you actually need/want.

Comment: But I don't have to pay if I upload it myself?

Comment: Appstore is free as far as I know. That's where the research comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I recently fell in love with the [Gideros Mobile](http://www.giderosmobile.com/) framework, works on both Mac and Windows, also its supposed to be working under Linux if you use wine.

Possible LUA mobile frameworks:

- Moai (open-source and thus free)
- Corona SDK ($199 per platform)
- Gideros Mobile (Free with Gideros splash screen, $149 to remove splash screen)

I looked and downloaded Moai, but its not very straightforward about how to use it, read a lot of documentation, but felt like I was still far of from starting. Could be just me.

Played around with Corona SDK, also looks pretty good, but a after reading [this](http://www.pixelenvision.com/2202/we-have-stopped-developing-with-the-corona-sdk/) article I decided to go for Gideros.

**Gideros**:
Gideros comes with a IDE and I was up and running in no time.
The good thing about Gideros is it works with a player over network, you can instantly see the results on your mobile device or local player, but with the player on the device its very easy to test the accelerometer and how the touch is responding as if it was a ready build app. Leading to very fast feedback.

The Android player is distributed with the SDK, the iOS player needs to be build manually in Xcode and needs a Apple developer account.

Also note the Gideros forums are great place for examples and discussions, the developers are active on the forums and the response has been really great and fast. It feels like a great community.

Answer (score 0):

I do just that C++ dev on Windows and Mac for Mac, Windows, iOS and Android. The solution is to use C++ and work with a middleware integrating multiple cross-platform libraries. This way I am able to compile the same project for iOS on mac and for a custom emulator on Windows.

Unity is a good framework which allows you to share code and resources across multiple platforms. If you want something that works out of the box it would be wise to have a look at that.

Writing such a middleware is possible. If you are two working together you can push forward quickly a prototype. You simply have to write your code for one platform once, then write your own interface and move all the platform specific code to dedicated files/libs.

It's what I have currently. The only down side is that my compile chain does not currently support compiling for iOS from Visual Studio yet.